# The limit of $e^{\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}}$ as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, exponential-function

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} e^{\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}}$$

This really should be a simple limit question, I've done similar things many times before, but I'm very out of practice with limits and cannot for the life of me figure this one out. Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Before trying to prove anything, the first thing one should do is guess the answer. If you have no idea what it should be, a plot usually will give you a good idea. Try typing `exp(1/(x^2+y^2))` into [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=exp%281/%28x^2%2By^2%29%29) or [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%281%2F%28x^2%2By^2%29%29) first.

Comment: Thank you for the answers everyone. I could see intuitively that the denominator approached zero, but I assumed that I needed to use some kind of formal system.

Comment: Calculate $e^{1/(x^2+y^2)}$ for values of $x^2+y^2$ fairly close to $0$. Or just think about it. If $x^2+y^2=0.01$, then we are looking at $e^{100}$, huge.

Comment: I know, I understood the intuition before I posted, it's just that math isn't usually solved by saying "well, just look at it!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The denominator of the exponent tends to zero from above, no matter how $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$. So the exponent grows without bound to $+\infty$. Hence the expression itself does as well. (Some may say the limit doesn't exist since it is infinite, but that's a matter of convention.)

If the numerator were $-1$ instead of $1$, the exponent would tend to $-\infty$, so the expression would tend to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x^2+y^2=r^2$. This is the equation of a circle of radius $r$. Saying that $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ here means that the radius of this circle is approaching zero. So we can transform this to a one variable limit:

$$ \lim_{r\to 0} y=\lim_{r\to 0} e^{\frac{1}{r^2}}$$

Now note that
$$\log y=\frac{1}{r^2}\rightarrow \infty,$$
as $ r\to 0$. So $y \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

As $(x,y)\rightarrow 0$, $x^2+y^2 \rightarrow 0$ while always remaining positive.  Since $\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{1}{t} = +\infty$, we find that $\lim_{(x,y)\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} = +\infty$.  Finally, since $\lim_{t\to +\infty} e^t = +\infty$, we string it all together to get:

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} e^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}} = e^{\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}} = +\infty
$$